# docker-compose error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When executing the following command:

```
$ sudo docker-compose -f custom-docker-compose.yml up -d
```

I see this normal output:

```
Pulling mymd-db (mariadb:10.5.6)...
10.5.6: Pulling from library/mariadb
6a5697faee43: Pulling fs layer
ba13d3bc422b: Pulling fs layer
a254829d9e55: Pulling fs layer
2ee2cadd29fc: Waiting
6915a184049d: Waiting
5ca6ffdb5f56: Waiting
1537f7bbef8b: Waiting
5790e54322d1: Waiting
ea98cb829471: Waiting
```

But then, out of the blue, I get the following error:

> ERROR: error pulling image configuration: Get
> https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/c4/c4655f911514fc440...Gmo%3D:
> EOF

This happens from time to time. I don't know why. Does anybody know how to fix it or any workaround? I am running a CentOS server.

Answer (score 0):

vim /etc/resolv.conf ,add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

---

```
service docker restart
```

And try again.
Most often than not,this is because of problems with your network